# Act of omission and commission

Tags: phrase-usage

What is meant by *the act of omission and commission* and when we imply this phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acts (or sins) of omission and commission are, respectively, things you have failed to do, and things you have done.

The terms are often used in legalistic or canon law contexts.  One might find the phrase "whether by omission or commission" in a contract, say, or a religious tract that ranks human misdeeds according to how evil they are might speak of "sins of omission" and "sins of commission".

Comment: The Book of Common Prayer expresses it thus: "Most merciful God, we confess that we have sinned against you [...] by what we have done, and by what we have left undone."